# Put back to original state

Tags: word-choice

Can you say this if you want to ask whether or not you have to revise some words as in the version when it was not revised?

Do you mean I have to put it back to original state??

Can you say this in almost all cases? For example, about my hair weirdly cut at the barber shop, you say, please put it back to original state. Or when someone touched my personal items and you say, put it back to original state. Are these O.K??

Comment: Why? Is there a general word for this in your language? In English you can say undo it, restore it, revert it, roll back, replace (formal for place it back), put back etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit off. In an informal context I would say "please make it how it was", and in a formal context I would say, "please restore it to its original state".

Answer (score 0):

"Put back to original state"

Q1. Can you say this if you want to ask whether or not you have to revise some words as in the version when it was not revised?

A. You CAN say "put back to original state", but more commonly with text or documents or editing "revert" or "roll back" or "undo" is used when talking about changes.

Q2. Do you mean I have to put it back to original state??

A. Yes, if you made change to a text or document or writing, change it back to its state before you made any changes.

Q3. Can you say this in almost all cases?

A. Most likely not, or if you do try to apply it to all cases it'll at least sound weird in certain cases.

Q4.  For example, about my hair weirdly cut at the barber shop, you say, please put it back to original state.

A. You CAN say that. Or "make it how it was before."

Q5. Or when someone touched my personal items and you say, put it back to original state.

A. This would sound a little strange. If someone's taken an item and moved it from its original position, you would most likely say "Put it back." The original state of an item that's been moved sounds strange because the item's original state was for example "motionless and lying on a shelf." Here you want to want to emphasise restoring the moved item's position, not so much state.